# Binding not working when set from ParentControl to UserControl

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding

I have a MainWindow which has a UserControl.

The MainWindow is bound to a ViewModel which is it's DataContext.

Now using the MainWindowViewModel, I want to bind certain controls in the UserControl.

The UserControl has a DependencyProperty for each element that I want to Bind .

From the MainWindow I am Binding the DependencyProperties of the UserControl to the MainWindowViewModel, but bindings aren't working.

MainWindow XAML:

```
<Grid >       
    <userControls:MultiSelectEnvironmentContextControl  EnvironmentVersions="{Binding EnvironmentVersions}"  x:Name="MultiSelectEnvironmentContextControl" Margin="10"  />       

</Grid>
```

UserControl XAML:

```
    <ComboBox Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" x:Name="ComboBoxVersions"  SelectedIndex="0" Margin="10" ItemsSource="{Binding EnvironmentVersions}">
       <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <TextBlock Text="Version " />
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" />
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ComboBox>
```

UserControl Code behind:

```
public partial class MultiSelectEnvironmentContextControl 
{        
    public MultiSelectEnvironmentContextControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = this;
    }

    public IEnumerable<string> EnvironmentVersions
    {
        get { return (IEnumerable<string>)GetValue(EnvironmentVersionsProperty); }
        set { SetValue(EnvironmentVersionsProperty, value); }
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for EnvironmentVersions.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty EnvironmentVersionsProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("EnvironmentVersions", typeof(IEnumerable<string>), typeof(MultiSelectEnvironmentContextControl), new PropertyMetadata(default(IEnumerable<string>)));


}
```

MainWindow ViewModel:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows;
using Geico.Applications.Business.CoverageTestHarness.DomainLayer;

namespace Geico.Applications.Business.CoverageTestHarness.UIWPF.ViewModels
{
    class TestRunnerControlViewModel: ViewModelBase
    {

        private DomainFacade domainFacade;


        /// <summary>
        /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="TestRunnerControlViewModel"/> class.
        /// </summary>
        public TestRunnerControlViewModel()
        {
            domainFacade = ((App) Application.Current).DomainFacade;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets the environment versions.
        /// </summary>
        /// <value>
        /// The environment versions.
        /// </value>
        public IEnumerable<string> EnvironmentVersions
        {
            get
            {
                return domainFacade.GetEnvironmentVersions();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What binding errors are in output?

Comment: @netaholic I don't see any errors in output window. Just that  the data isn't coming which is supposed to come after binding.

Comment: Your ViewModel class is private. Make it public

Comment: @netaholic It was internal, made it public now. Same result. Can't see any data.

Comment: Could you please make a simple project illustrating the problem? Just 1 dependency property, usercontrol, mainwindow, viewmodel and test data without using 3rd party libraries.

Comment: @netaholic Sure, but how do i share it?

Comment: just edit your question and post listing, as you did before

Comment: @netaholic I have updated the post to just focus on 1 dependency property

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87150/discussion-between-charu-and-netaholic).

Answer (score 0):

Your mistake was setting datacontect in usercontrol constructor.
Just remove

```
this.DataContext = this;
```

in

```
public void MultiSelectEnvironmentContextControl ()
{
    ...
}
```

Here is my code:
MainWindow.xaml

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication8.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525" xmlns:userControls="clr-namespace:WpfApplication8">
<Grid >
    <userControls:UserControl1  EnvironmentVersions="{Binding EnvironmentVersions}"  x:Name="MultiSelectEnvironmentContextControl" Margin="10"  />

</Grid>
```

MainWindow.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace WpfApplication8
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            this.DataContext = new TestRunnerControlViewModel();
            InitializeComponent();

        }
    }
}
```

UserControl.cs

```
  using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
  using System.Windows.Navigation;
  using System.Windows.Shapes;

  namespace WpfApplication8
  {
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for UserControl1.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class UserControl1 : UserControl
    {
        public UserControl1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    public IEnumerable<string> EnvironmentVersions
    {
        get { return (IEnumerable<string>)GetValue(EnvironmentVersionsProperty); }
        set { SetValue(EnvironmentVersionsProperty, value); }
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for EnvironmentVersions.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty EnvironmentVersionsProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("EnvironmentVersions", typeof(IEnumerable<string>), typeof(UserControl1), new PropertyMetadata(default(IEnumerable<string>)));
    }
}
```

vm.cs

```
  using System;
  using System.Collections.Generic;
  using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
  using System.Linq;
  using System.Windows;

  namespace WpfApplication8
  {
    class TestRunnerControlViewModel 
    {
        //  private DomainFacade domainFacade;
        public TestRunnerControlViewModel()
        {
            //domainFacade = ((App)Application.Current).DomainFacade;
        }

        public IEnumerable<string> EnvironmentVersions
        {
            get
            {
                return new List<string>() { "test", "test2" };
            }
        }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Well I was setting the DataContext in usercontrol because I wanted t bind the controls to Dependecy Properties, If we don't do this I think it is working because the DataContext of parent which is the MainWindow is being accessed from UserControl which is not the right way to make it work.

Comment: " I think it is working because the DataContext of parent which is the MainWindow is being accessed from UserControl" Thats exactly the case. Why would you be against it? Its intended behaviour

Comment: If you want to bind usercontrols's properties to another controls property you should specify sourceelement in binding

Comment: In that case we don't need DP on UserControl. Initially I also did what you did i.e. just bind using the parent's DataContext, but my code review was rejected. Reason I was given was It is not a recommended practice because it leads to coupling between UserControl and Parent. Right way to do is to use Bind from ParetCntrol to the DP in UserControl

Comment: So do you want to bind usercontrol to its own value then, but set the binding in parent control or what? According to your code the value, which you want to be provided to the usercontrol is stored in viewmodel. How not to link parent and child then?